# How to set passwords in configmap

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, devops, configmap

I want to configure passwords in the config map.YAML instead of deployment.yaml.able to set username and other variables.attcahing the config map.YAML file which I worked on.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: poc-configmapconfiguration-configmap
data:
  Environment: [[.Environment]]
  dockerRegistryUrl: [[.Env.dockerRegistryUrl]]
  CassandraSettings__CassandraPassword:
          valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
                name: abcd-passwords
                key: "[[ .Environment ]]-abcd-cassandra-password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested its **better practice to use secrets to store passwords** 
**Secrets obscure your data using a Base64 encoding** so it is good practice to use Secrets for confidential data over using ConfigMaps.

If you perform a explain on ConfigMap field to get more details from CLI it self on the ConfigMap.data it accepts map of strings.

```
$ kubectl explain ConfigMap.data
KIND:     ConfigMap
VERSION:  v1

FIELD:    data <map[string]string>

DESCRIPTION:
     Data contains the configuration data. Each key must consist of alphanumeric
     characters, '-', '_' or '.'. Values with non-UTF-8 byte sequences must use
     the BinaryData field. The keys stored in Data must not overlap with the
     keys in the BinaryData field, this is enforced during validation process.
```

So above **yaml structure you used should throw a error on creation time** something like below ..

```
invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data
```

**Refer this git request for such feature request , which is already closed with no support considered.**

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79224

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I think we can't set the passwords inside the configmap.

Comment: The use of Base64 is not why you should use Secrets, it's that they support at-rest encryption and ConfigMaps do not. It also helps to segregate data for RBAC purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more common to use a Secret, as you can see from the `secretKeyRef`, however an equivalent `configMapRef` exists and be used in the same way.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply., you mean can we use the 'configMapRef ' instead of secretKeyRef in the configmap.yaml?

Comment: Both secretRef and configMapRef are keys used in pod configurations.